# Word Count with custom delimiter (|) using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a newbie to Pig latin.I wanted to process the below file and count the most occurred word.

> Hadoop|is|an|open|source|Java-based|programming|framework|that|supports|
>   the|processing|and|storage|of|extremely|large|data|sets|in|a|distributed|computing|environment.

The file contains a `|` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few examples of word count examples out there.In any case,here's the one with delimiter '|'

```
lines = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (line:chararray);
newlines = FOREACH lines GENERATE REPLACE(line,'\\|',' ') AS newline;
words = FOREACH newlines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(newline)) as word;
grouped = GROUP words BY word;
w_count = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);
DUMP w_count;
```

Comment: @inquistive_mind you could escape the | by \\                                                       i.e `newlines = FOREACH lines GENERATE REPLACE(line,'\\|',' ') AS newline`